# Oracle "UPDATE" command returns 0 rows affected in my ASP .NET application but the SQL statement itself works in PL/SQL

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have this ASP.NET project working with Oracle, I have the following code for operating the DB:

```
public int cmd_Execute_Orcl(string strSql, params OracleParameter[] paramArray)
{
    OracleCommand myCmd = new OracleCommand();
    try
    {
        myCmd.Connection = myOrclConn;
        myCmd.CommandText = strSql;

        foreach (OracleParameter temp in paramArray)
        {
            myCmd.Parameters.Add(temp);
        }
        ConnectionManage(true);
        int i = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCmd.Parameters.Clear();
        return i;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally 
    {
        myCmd.Dispose();
        ConnectionManage(false);
    }
}
```

"ConnectionManage()" turns on or off the connection, the following code is from data access layer of the program:

```
public string Edit_DAL(string id, string jh, string jz, string jd, string wd, string gzwz, string qxlx, string sx, string jx, string jb, string cfdd, string zjqssj, string zjzzsj, string bz)
    {
        string sql = "update JH set jh = :jh, jz = :jz, wd = :wd, jd = :jd, gzwz = :gzwz, qxlx = :qxlx, sx = :sx, jx = :jx, jb = :jb, cfdd = :cfdd, zjqssj = TO_DATE(:zjqssj, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), zjzzsj = TO_DATE(:zjzzsj, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), bz = :bz where ID = :idy";
        string result = null;
        {
            String[] temp1 = zjqssj.Split('/');
            String[] temp2 = zjzzsj.Split('/');

            string tempString = "";

            if (temp1[2].Length < 2)
            {
                temp1[2] = temp1[2].Insert(0, "0");
            }

            
            for (int i = 0; i < temp1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    temp1[i] = temp1[i].Insert(0, "/");
                }
                tempString += temp1[i].ToString();
            }

            zjqssj = tempString;
            tempString = "";

            if (temp2[2].Length < 2)
            {
                temp2[2] = temp2[2].Insert(0, "0");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < temp2.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    temp2[i] = temp2[i].Insert(0, "/");
                }
                tempString += temp2[i].ToString();
            }

            zjzzsj = tempString;
            tempString = "";
        }
        OracleParameter[] pars ={
                                new OracleParameter(":idy",id),
                                new OracleParameter(":jh",jh),
                                new OracleParameter(":jz",jz),
                                new OracleParameter(":jd",jd),
                                new OracleParameter(":wd",wd),
                                new OracleParameter(":gzwz",gzwz),
                                new OracleParameter(":qxlx",qxlx),
                                new OracleParameter(":sx",sx),
                                new OracleParameter(":jx",jx),
                                new OracleParameter(":jb",jb),
                                new OracleParameter(":cfdd",cfdd),
                                new OracleParameter(":zjqssj",(zjqssj.Replace('/', '-') + " 00:00:00")),
                                new OracleParameter(":zjzzsj",(zjzzsj.Replace('/', '-') + " 00:00:00")),
                                new OracleParameter(":bz",bz)
                            };
        try
        {
            SqlHelper.cmd_Execute_Orcl(sql, pars);
            result = "ok";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = "no" + "=" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Here's where the strange thing happens, when I hit this part of the code, there's no exception, it returns 0, no rows affected, all the values of the parameters are normal, with expected value, then I tried to run the command in PL/SQL and it works, the row is correctly updated, delete function is also referencing the same "cmd_Execute_Orcl" method and it works just fine, and for the other object the edit function is working perfectly, I am posting the code below:

```
public string Edit(string OriginalId, string EditUserAccount, string EditUserName, string EditUserMobile, string EditDeptId, string EditRoleId, string EditRoleName)
    {
        string sql = "update AuthUser set UserAccount=:EditUserAccount, UserName=:EditUserName, UserMobile=:EditUserMobile, DepartmentId=:EditDeptId, RID=:EditRoleId, RoleName=:EditRoleName where ID=:OriginalId";
        OracleParameter[] pars ={
                                new OracleParameter(":EditUserAccount",EditUserAccount),
                                new OracleParameter(":EditUserName",EditUserName),
                                new OracleParameter(":EditUserMobile",EditUserMobile),
                                new OracleParameter(":EditDeptId",EditDeptId),
                                new OracleParameter(":EditRoleId",EditRoleId),
                                new OracleParameter(":EditRoleName",EditRoleName),
                                new OracleParameter(":OriginalId",OriginalId),
                            };
        try
        {
            SqlHelper.cmd_Execute_Orcl(sql, pars);
            return "ok";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string test = ex.Message;
            return "no";
        }
    }
```

In the expected table, column ID is nvarchar2 with default value of sys_guid(), column ZJQSSJ and column ZJZZSJ is of type date, all other columns are of type varchar2, I have also tried executing "COMMIT" and reformating data for date, but the same problem is still there, plz help...

Comment: if you execute the same command in Oracle. you will know what the difference is.

Comment: @EminNiftiyev, I did try running the command in PL/SQL if that's what you mean, and it works and that's also what confuses me most